# Java: Cannot serialize object with a DateTimeFormatter property?

Tags: java, oop, serialization, io

I am trying to write a serialization of an object (`Match`) to a file. However, when I run my code, I receive the following code, stating that the object cannot be serialized because it contains a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) property which is not serializable:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

The problem is that I can't modify the `DateTimeFormatter` class to implement [`java.io.Seralizable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html), as that interface is marked `final`.

Any suggestions on how to workaround this issue?

Below is my code:

**Match.java**

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Match implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String timeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
    private final DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);

    public Match() {
    }
}
```

**SaveSerializedMatch.java**:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SaveSerializedMatch{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Match match = new Match();
        
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Match.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    
            out.writeObject(match);
            out.close();
    
            fileOut.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `inputFormatter` `transient` (and non-`final`), then implement `readObject` in `Match`. Something like `private final void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {in.defaultReadObject(); this.inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);}` should work.

Comment: I don't see any reason why both the format and the formatter can't be `static` here.